# Loop not running and get struck with the first iteration -Python Knapsack problem (No error)

Tags: python, function, loops, lambda, knapsack-problem

Self new to Python and trying my skills on already run codes. Unable to get the output as required as a list of output rather getting only the first input and the details.

Function code blocks.
block-1

```
class Food(object):
    def __init__(self,n,v,w):
        self.name=n
        self.value=v
        self.calories=w
        
    def getValue(self):
        return self.value
    
    def getCost(self):
        return self.calories
    
    def density(self):
        return self.getValue()/self.getCost()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ': <'+str(self.value) +','+str(self.calories)+'>'
```

block-2

```
def buildMenu(names,values,calories):
    menu=[]
    for i in range(len(values)):
        menu.append(Food(names[i],values[i],calories[i]))
        return menu
```

block-3

```
def greedy(items,maxCost,keyFunction):
    itemsCopy=sorted(items,key=keyFunction,reverse=True)
    result=[]
    totalValue,totalCost=0.0,0.0
    
    for i in range(len(itemsCopy)):
        if(totalCost+itemsCopy[i].getCost())<=maxCost:
            result.append(itemsCopy[i])
            totalCost+=itemsCopy[i].getCost()
            totalValue+=itemsCopy[i].getValue()
    return (result,totalValue)
```

block-4

```
def testGreedy(items,constraint,keyFunction):
    taken,val=greedy(items,constraint,keyFunction)
    print('Total value of items taken',val)
    for item in taken:
        print('  ',item)
```

block-5

```
def testGreedys(foods,maxUnits):
    print('Use greedy by value to allocate',maxUnits,'calories')
    testGreedy(foods,maxUnits,Food.getValue)
    print('\nUse greedy by cost to allocate',maxUnits,'calories')
    testGreedy(foods,maxUnits,lambda x:1/Food.getCost(x)) 
    print('\nUse greedy by density to allocate',maxUnits,'calories')
    testGreedy(foods,maxUnits,Food.density)
```

Main code blocks and input.

```
names=['wine','beer','pizza','burger','fries','cola','apple','donut','cake']
values=[89,90,95,100,90,79,50,10]
calories=[123,154,258,354,365,150,95,195]
foods=buildMenu(names,values,calories)
testGreedys(foods,750)
```

Current output below is taking only the first element.Actually it should run for the entire input item list in names.

```
Use greedy by value to allocate 750 calories
Total value of items taken 89.0
   wine: <89,123>

Use greedy by cost to allocate 750 calories
Total value of items taken 89.0
   wine: <89,123>

Use greedy by density to allocate 750 calories
Total value of items taken 89.0
   wine: <89,123>
```

Request your help to debug and find out why the complete loop not running as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return` for `menu` is in the loop when you build a menu. This causes it to only ever return one item in the menu, move it back one indentation.

```
def buildMenu(names,values,calories):
    menu=[]
    for i in range(len(values)):
        menu.append(Food(names[i],values[i],calories[i]))
    return menu

Total value of items taken 318.0
   apple: <50,95>
   wine: <89,123>
   cola: <79,150>
   beer: <90,154>
   donut: <10,195>
```

Comment: It worked .Thank you for enlightening me. That was really a grave mistake from my end.

Comment: It happens! Always good to remember that `return` will exit the function when it is called.

Comment: Thank you for the tips which is very important when especially running nested loops we shall not be able to identify the problems.